# How to append a button in each loop iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array, arr. I want to append buttons to `#enquirieswall` for every object in the array. I have tried various methods but none has worked so far. This is what I have came up with so far:

```
<script>
var arr = [{"userid": "jim", "title":"help"}, {"userid": "pim", "title":"hello"}]  

var i;
$("enquirieswall").empty();
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href","#");
  a.setAttribute("class","ui-btn");
  //added according to comments on my question
  a.textContent = arr[i].title;
  a.setAttribute("onclick", "window.location='enquiriesdetails.php?userid=" + arr[i].userid +"'");  
  $("#enquirieswall").append(a);
}
</script>

<div id="enquirieswall"></div>
```

Currently the results are links side by side with each other, I want them to be in buttons instead.

Comment: Your `a` elements don't have any textContents?

Comment: syntax error in the array, missing `,` and no content in for the anchor elements to display - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6ppj8euq/2/

Comment: or https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6ppj8euq/3/

Comment: You are absolutely right, var arr is actually a JSON response made manually and I have made the changes accordingly! I finally got results but I want them to look like buttons instead of links to, will get to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

changed createElement to button and ui-btn to btn

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                      var a = document.createElement("button");
                      a.setAttribute("href", "#");
                      //a.textContent = arr[i].title;
                      a.innerHTML = arr[i].title.toString();
                      a.setAttribute("class", "btn");
                      a.setAttribute("type", "button");
                      a.setAttribute("onclick", "window.location='enquiriesdetails.php?userid=" + arr[i].userid + "'");
                      $("#enquirieswall").append(a);
                    }
```